# Trying to bind a variable to a row in a Factory array (angular)

Tags: arrays, angularjs, factory

I have a factory that is storing an array where objects are pushed in as buttons are pressed. I want to bind a variable on a page to the first object in this array. Here's my factory:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.factory('errorHandler', function () {
    var errorArray = [];
    function compareObjs(a,b) {
        if(a.type === "Alert" && b.type === "Info") {
            return -1;
        }
        else if (a.type === "Info" && b.type === "Alert") {
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            if(a.timestamp > b.timestamp) {
                return -1;
            }
            else if (a.timestamp < b.timestamp) {
                return 1;
            }
            else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    errorArray.addError = (function (type, message) {
        var timestamp = Date.now();
        errorArray.push({type: type, message: message, timestamp: timestamp});
        errorArray.sort(compareObjs);
    });
    errorArray.removeError = (function (index) {
        if(errorArray.length >= index) {
            errorArray.splice(index, 1);
        }
    });
    return errorArray;
})
```

And Controller:

```
.controller('ErrorModalCtrl', ['errorHandler', '$scope', function (errorHandler, $scope) {
    $scope.errorModal = {
        title: 'Notification Centre',
        errorList: []
    };
    $scope.addError = function(type, message) {
        errorHandler.addError(type, message);
        console.log(errorHandler.length+"just added");
    };
    $scope.errorModal.errorList = errorHandler;
    $scope.mostRecentError = errorHandler[0];
}]);
```

So when the page loads the array will be empty, but as I press these buttons `$scope.addError` is triggered and objects are pushed to the array. I have checked this is working correctly. However, on my HTML (within the scope of the controller) I have

```
{{mostRecentError.message}}
```

and this never populates. Why is this the case? Have I misunderstood the dependencies somewhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
$scope.mostRecentError = errorHandler[0];
```

is executed when your controller is instantiated. At that moment, the error hasn't pressed any button yet. So `errorHandler[0]` is undefined, and `$scope.mostRecentError` is thus initialized to `undefined`.

When the user pressed the button errorHandler will have its first element, but that line of code won't be magically reexecuted, so `$scope.mostRecentError` wil stay undefined.

Instead of initializing a variable, you should define a function in the controller, that returns the most recent error. That, or `$scope.mostRecentError` must be initialized inside the `addError()` function of the controller, to be updated every time an error is added.

Comment: That makes sense...but how do I create a variable that will be the most recent error object?

Comment: I updated my answer. The best way is to use a function instead of a variable. That function should return `errorHandler[0]`. And the view would have `{{mostRecentError().message}}`.

Comment: Amazing...tried initialising it inside the `addError()` function and it also works. Thanks!